# Call Generic method using runtime type and cast return object

Tags: c#, generics

I'm using reflection to call a generic method with a type determined at runtime.  My code is as follows:

```
Type tType = Type.GetType(pLoadOut.Type);
MethodInfo method = typeof(ApiSerialiseHelper).GetMethod("Deserialise", new Type[] { typeof(string) });
MethodInfo generic = method.MakeGenericMethod(tType);
generic.Invoke(obj, new object[] { pLoadOut.Data });
```

This works ok.  However the generic.Invoke method returns an object, but what I would like is the type determined at runtime.  Is this possible with this approach, or is there a better option?

Mark

Comment: What do you mean by `but what I would like is the type determined at runtime`?

Comment: Assuming tType has a method called DoSomething().  I would like to be able to do this; var a = generic.Invoke(obj, new object[] { pLoadOut.Data }); a.DoSomething();

Comment: What is the actual static return type of `Deserialize`?  Delegate variance might be useful to you.

Comment: Deserialize is a generic method, the return type is T.  What is Delegate variance?  Any good examples/articles?

Comment: Delegate variance says that if you have, for example, a method that returns `List`, you can bind a delegate that returns `IList` to that method.  Eric Lippert has written quite a bit about it, I'll find you a link in a sec...  I've also got example code in my answer.

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2007/10/19/covariance-and-contravariance-in-c-part-three-member-group-conversion-variance.aspx  and a whole series of related articles: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/tags/Covariance+and+Contravariance/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The type IS determined at runtime.  It's the type of the reference variable that is object, the actual instance is strongly typed.

That's the best that can be done, considering that you're using reflection to dynamically get access to a method that the compiler has no type information for -- it might not even exist in the build environment.

EDIT: If you know something about the type returned by `Deserialize`, then you can take advantage of delegate variance.  For example:

```
Type tType = Type.GetType(pLoadOut.Type);
MethodInfo method = typeof(ApiSerialiseHelper).GetMethod("Deserialise", new Type[] { typeof(string) });
MethodInfo generic = method.MakeGenericMethod(tType);
Converter<string,ISomething> deser = (Converter<string,ISomething>)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Converter<string,ISomething>),generic);
ISomething result = deser(pLoadOut.Data);
```

Answer (score 0):

If the returned objects have a common ancestor or interface, then you can cast to them. If they don't, then they should, e.g. if all possible return types have a method named DoSomething(), then make an interface that has a method DoSomething().

Comment: And that interface must be known at compile-time, even if the most derived type is not.